# How to display number as an hour from duration in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, nsstring

Is there a way to display a number as an hour from a duration ?
For example i have a NSTimeInterval value containing `127` and i want to display `02:07`.

What's the better way to do that ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enjoy! :)

```
NSTimeInterval _timeInterval = 127.f;

NSInteger _hours = _timeInterval / 60;
NSInteger _minutes = (NSInteger)_timeInterval % 60; 

NSLog(@"%02d:%02d", _hours, _minutes);
```

Comment: +1 Nice `%02d` string formatting. I haven't seen this before as I recently switched from python.

Answer (score 0):

```
value = (int) othervalue;    
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d:%2d",value/60,value%60];
```

- The `value/60` does integer division on the number, which throws out anything < 0. So 127 / 60 gives you 2.
- % (modulo) gives the remainder of division: 127 % 60 gives you 7.

The casting to `int` keeps you from getting an error from a float or double value (thanks for the comment holex).

And the `%2d` gives you 2-digit format (thanks for the other comment Rene Jennrich).

Comment: if the value is a `float` or a `double` you will get an error message for the `value % 60`.

Comment: `value = (int) othervalue` would fix that